# How to generate an enable signal when a bus value is in a very small range?

Tags: microprocessor, rom

I am trying to build an MC68010 single-board system, and the first four 16-bit words (I am treating it as a 23-bit word-addressed system) of memory need to read a constant value (00100000h 00007C00h) so the CPU knows where to find the ROM. Is there a good way to determine when the address, encoded on 23 pins, is between 0 and 3? What I want to do is to OR together 21 of the address lines, creating an enable signal that is only active when the address is within range. Is this the best way to accomplish such a result, and if so, how do I do it efficiently? If not, what is the best way?

Comment: To be clear: Are you trying to determine when your 23 bits are from `0x000000` to `0x000003`? Are you coding in C, assembly, or something else? (or are you performing your OR in hardware?)

Comment: Usually this is done by locating a ROM at address 0.  Is there a particular reason you can't do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is less complicated than I expected.

First, a little about the '010. When it starts up, it reads the initial stack pointer from address 0, and it reads the initial program counter from address 2. At address 4 is the beginning of the Interrupt Vector Table. However, this table, starting with the '010, can be relocated in memory. This means that even if the IVT pointer references ROM at reset, it can be changed to point to a RAM location. I forgot about this, and assumed that the first four words of memory would have to be ROM, and the area starting with the fifth word would need to be RAM to store a mutable IVT. This would lead to difficulty with chip selection, as the first four addresses would select a different chip than the next several thousand. I thought I had to do some trickery with DIP switches and OR gates/decoders to get this awkward memory layout to work.

I actually don't. I can put my 64-kiloword ROM at the very beginning of the address space, and store the initialization values at the beginning of the ROM. Then, I can have a program that switches out the default IVT pointer with a correct one that references RAM. This way, I avoid the ugly four-word ROM and the IVT stays in RAM where it belongs.

Comment: If this is the correct answer then you can accept it even though you wrote it yourself.

Comment: Yes, but it is making me wait until tomorrow...

Comment: That's actually a good thing. It allows time for others who might be put off by an acceptance to post an answer. One or two revolutions of the globe gives everyone a chance.

Answer (score 0):

This function is in general called a *decoder*.

You are correct that for this particular instance, the equivalent function is achieved by ORing the 21 highest-order bits.

A more typical decoder chip will have several outputs, each one going high for a different range of the input bits. Also, 21-bit-wider are not AFAIK commonly available as a single chip, but could be constructed by combining a few smaller decoders.